# Нужно определения дня недели

Tags: java, время, switch, case

Код на java. Нужно чтобы от пользователя запрашивался номер дня недели, а получалось название. Не пойму, что не так. Помогите, пожалуйста, Добрые Люди

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sw = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите число: ");
        int week = sw.nextInt();
        sw.nextLine();
        System.out.println(Month.dayOFWeek(week));
       // System.out.println("The day is "+day);
        
    
}

class Month{
    static String dayOFWeek(int week) {
        String day = "";
        
        switch (week) {
            case 1:
                day = "Monday";
                break;
            case 2:
                day = "Tuesday";
                break;
            case 3:
                day = "Wednesday";
                break;
            // match the value of week
            case 4:
                day = "Thursday";
                break;
            case 5:
                day = "Friday";
                break;
            case 6:
                day = "Saturday";
                break;
            case 7:
                day = "Sunday";
                break;
            default:
                day = "---";
                break;
        }
        return day;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: А для чего вам `switch`? Как вариант: создали массив из строк, из которых забираете нужную индексом равным декременту введённого числа.

Comment: То есть, `switch` это какой-то сакральный тотем в данном случае? В вашем случае для чего-то создано два класса, при этом `switch` висит мёртвым грузом в одном из них. Как по-вашему, почему код не работает?

Comment: Простите, но вам скорее следует обратиться на [этот](https://www.govnokod.ru) ресурс.

Comment: В классе `Month` создайте метод, в котором реализовывалась какая-то логика со `switch`, и вызывайте его.

Comment: В последней версии вопрос содержит вполне рабочий код, так что первоначальная проблема потеряна.

Answer (score 1):

1. некорректное использование метода nextInt();

при вводе и нажатии "Enter"  `nextInt()`считывает число, а перевод на новую строку
nextLine ("\n") остаётся и может быть непредвиденное поведение.
надо либо после nextInt прописывать  nextLine

```
int week = sw.nextInt();
sw.nextLine();
```

либо парсить

```
  int week = Integer.parseInt(sw.nextLine());
```

2)в классе Month создай статик метод принимающий число и возвращающий день

```
  static String dayOFWeek(int week) {
        String day = "";
//switch
return day;
}
```

в мейне считываешь число и передаёшь в метод

```
  System.out.println(Month.dayOFWeek(week));
```

если версия jdk выше 11 или 13 не помню точно, то можно так написать

```
class Month {

    static String dayOFWeek(int week) {

        return switch (week) {
            case 1 -> "Monday";
            case 2 -> "Tuesday";
            case 3 -> "Wednesday";
            case 4 -> "Thursday";
            case 5 -> "Friday";
            case 6 -> "Saturday";
            case 7 -> "Sunday";
            default -> "---";
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Немного Вас не поняла, код поправила, не работает

Comment: в ide надо писать, будут подсвечиваться ошибки... надо либо класс Month сделать static, либо перед классом month добавить скобку `}` и в конце класса одну убрать.

Comment: Не помогает(...

Comment: а что пишет, в чём проблема?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method dayOFWeek(int)
  location: class javaapplication5.JavaApplication5.Month

Comment: скопируй код что в вопросе и добавь перед class Month `static`, чтобы было static class Month

Comment: через консоль делаешь?

Comment: СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ!!! ВСЕ ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ!!!

Comment: С методом `nextInt()` вроде проблем не было в первоначальном коде

Comment: @Alex Rudenko я писал что может быть непредвиденное поведение при использовании метода nextInt. а тут да, одно считывание, сложностей не должно быть....

Comment: `ВСЕ ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ!!!` - значит, ответ нужно пометить галочкой как решение